# ews java api - How to set permission/classification (public/restricted/internal) to Email message

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am drafting email in custom folder.

```
EmailMessage msg= new EmailMessage(service);
msg.setSubject("Hello world!");
msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Draft email using the EWS Java API."));
msg.getToRecipients().add("someone@contoso.com");
// Tried to set extended property but not worked
ExtendedPropertyDefinition headerProperty = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(
                    DefaultExtendedPropertySet.InternetHeaders,
                    "X-Classification",
                    MapiPropertyType.String);
            msg.setExtendedProperty(headerProperty,"Provision X-header Internet message header");
msg.save(CUSTOM_FOLDER_ID);
```

I came to know that extended property will be helpful for classification/permission header. 
Ref link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-provision-x-headers-by-using-ews-in-exchange
But how to set classification/permission ? X-Classification-Restricted something like this or any other way ?

I dont want to use setImportance / setSensitivity methods.

Manually we are setting in following way 
[image]

Expectation from ews api to set classification/permission from code
[image]

How to set **permission**/**classification**(public/**Restricted**/Internal) to EmailMessage using ews java api?

Code snippet of working example appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for the item property [sensivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.sensitivity?view=exchange-ews-api#Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_Item_Sensitivity)?

Comment: @LuCio  No- I dont want sensitivity property. I am looking for permission/Classification for EmailMessage.

Comment: @LuCio No, sensitivity not required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**x-iccategory** InternetHeaders is required to set classification/permission to email.

x-iccategory with value from **[1-4]** & supply value as **string**

Following are Values with classification/permission type of x-iccategory

**1=Highly,
2=Restricted,
3=Internal,
4=Public**

Following in sample code snippet

```
   EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(exchangeService);
                msg.setSubject("Ews api code....");        
                msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("** Email with classification using EWS Java API."));
                msg.setFrom(new EmailAddress("some1@test.com");
                msg.getToRecipients().add("some2@test.com");


            // Define the extended property
            ExtendedPropertyDefinition extPropDef = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.InternetHeaders, "x-iccategory", MapiPropertyType.String);

            // Stamp the extended property with value on a message. 2- Restricted
            msg.setExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, "2");

            msg.send();
```

Classification/permission not applicable to email message from draft/custom folder

**Note** - Classification/Permission comes in picture when you trigger that email. 
Email goes to transport pipeline 1st and based on the value(Restricted/Public...) it gets applied

Comment: Where's the related document? Could you share it?